# Laravel routing not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Quick question,

EDIT: I do not know how to access other routes besides '/'
Here are the routes I want to access

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');

Route::get('foo', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Here is my routes. Via **php artisan routes**
[image]

I can successfully access **localhost/cartraderlaravel/public**
It takes me to HomeController@index

when I try to access foo or users I get 
[image]

I have tried

localhost/cartraderlaravel/public/users
localhost/cartraderlaravel/users
localhost/cartraderlaravel/foo
localhost/cartraderlaravel/public/foo

All of these return a "Not Found" error. Help anyone?

Comment: Thank you. I knew the answer was simple and I hesitated asking in the first place. Do you know why this practice is done?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the post. I have updated my question to further specify what I am confused with.

Comment: I do not understand. I am still having trouble accessing users @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64567/discussion-between-ryan-goo-and-arif-suhail-123).

Comment: I still am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am following the same directions as them but it is not working correctly. It may be my path variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should point your root directory to cartraderlaravel/public in WAMP so that you need not to visit localhost/cartraderlaravel/public. To do that in WAMP follow :

1. Click on WampServer icon in taskbar
2. Select Apache > httpd.conf from the pullup
3. Search for the term “DocumentRoot”
4. Change the DocumentRoot path to your custom directory
5. Search again for “DocumentRoot” again same procedure
6. Save your changes and “Restart All Services”

Answer (score 0):

Further research shows this is a common problem with WAMP. Something to do with Apache settings. I have moved to using a virtual network and everything works now